# Swapping values of macros

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

This may seem silly but I seem to have forgotten the order of replacement of macros. Can someone help me figure out how to correctly swap the values of two macros? Consider the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define var1 5
#define var2 10

#define _VAL(a) a
#define VAL(a) _VAL(a)


int main(){

    printf("var1 = %d, var2 = %d\n", var1, var2);

#define TEMP VAL(var1)
#undef var1
#define var1 VAL(var2)
#undef var2
#define var2 VAL(TEMP)

    printf("var1 = %d, var2 = %d\n", var1, var2);
}
```

All I want is to have `var1` to be replaced by 10 and `var2` to be replaced by 5. Any ideas of how to fix this mess?

I'm trying to use this to try to figure something out for this other question:

[C Macro to protect definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402174/c-macro-to-protect-definitions)

Comment: That seems unnecessarily complex and fragile. Is there another way to do whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't think you understand quite how macros work.  They don't have a value.  Macros simply replace one text string with another before compilation (well, basic ones).  Anyway, run the pre-processor on your code and look at the intermediate output (there is a compiler option for this; what compiler are you using?).  This will illuminate the source of your issue.

Comment: @jeffamaphone, I'm using gcc, How can I see the intermediate output. I'd like to test this on an example such as stringification: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification

Comment: I'm not as familiar with gcc, but I believe you use the `-E` option at the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done.
As @jeffamaphone explains in his comment, macro definitions are not assignments.
`#define A B` doesn't care about the value of `B`. It just remembers that `A` should be replaced to `B`. Later, when `A` is seen in the source, it's replaced to `B`, which may then be replaced again, with whatever `B` is defined to be at that time.